# Mapping Querystring array to object in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to implement server side processing for jQuery DataTables in MVC. I'm running into an issue with binding the querystring to the proper objects.

The querystring format for Datatables is as follows:

```
draw=
start=
length=
search[value]=
search[regex]=
order[i][column]=
order[i][dir]=
columns[i][data]=
columns[i][name]=
columns[i][searchable]=
columns[i][orderable]=
columns[i][search][value]=
columns[i][search][regex]=
```

where `i` is the index.

In MVC I have the following models setup:

```
public class DTParams
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List<DTColumn> columns { get; set; }
    public List<DTOrder> order { get; set; }
}

public class DTColumn
{
    public int data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
}

public class DTOrder
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is I can't seem to get the querystring to bind to the models I've setup. However `Request.QueryString["order[0][dir]"]` works perfectly fine. Is there something I'm missing that is preventing my request from being bound to the model? Is there a possible work around?

For clarification: The request sent to the server is generated and handled by DataTables.

Comment: Can you post the link to the page where the url format for datatables is documented? I only see Json in th documentation.

Comment: Does the server request *have* to be made with GET? I mean could you not use POST and add the datatable stuff in the request body?

Comment: Have a look at this: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part), particularly the class `jQueryDataTableParamModel`.

Comment: @markpsmith I had looked at that prior to posting. Unfortunately that is created against their legacy implementation. From what I've gathered reading around, it seems like datatables doesn't play well with the Model Binder. So to accomplish this I setup a custom Model Binder to handle the DataTables QueryString. Seems to be working well.